# Change title to data-title in anchor tag?

Tags: jquery

How in jQuery do i change `title` attribute to `data-title`?  I don't want the browser tooltip to show, along with the custom tooltip i've created.

```
<a title="my content"></a>
```

to

```
<a data-title="my content"></a>
```

Wordpress doesn't have an option to add custom attributes to menu in wp-admin, so i have to use jQuery. This is so when i hover over a menu link that the browser tooltip doesn't show and only the custom tooltip i've made shows.

How do i solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do the following:

```
$('a[title]').attr('data-title', function() {
    return $(this).attr('title');
}).removeAttr('title');
```

The reason this will work best is because you're working purely with attributes here. Using properties (`.prop()`) or object data (`.data()`) could possibly store the information you want as an attribute in the object. Namely, jQuery doesn't add a `data-title` attribute when you do something like `$('#myId').data('title', 'foo')`, but it will if you set the attribute like I did.

Alternatively, instead of `$(this).attr('title')`, you can use `this.title`, like Vohuman said in the comments to this answer, but that will have minimal difference in overall functionality or performance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(function() {
  var content =  $('a').attr('title');
  $('a').removeAttr('title');
  $('a').attr('data-title', content);
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('a').each(function(){
  var title = $(this).prop('title');
  $(this).removeProp('title');
  $(this).data('title',title);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the simplest way is probably:

```
$('a[title]').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        title = $this.attr('title');
    $this.removeAttr('title')
         .attr('data-title', title);
});
```